# Using labels for lstinputlisting

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I am using the `listings`package to include source code in my `.tex`-document. Now I would like to reference to these `lstinputlisting`s. Therrefore, I am using this

```
lstinputlisting[label=lst:mat.h, title=\textbf{src:} mat.h]{src/mat.h}
```

to include the file and

```
\ref{list:mat.h}
```

to reference to it. Now I do not get an error message, but instead of a number to this listing I only get the number of the (sub)section.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without using the `caption` option, the `\label` applies the `\@currentlabel` settings which has been modified by the last `\refstepcounter`, apparently in the OP this was some `\subsection` operation.

Solution: Apply `caption=...` as an option in the optional argument of `\lstinputlisting` -- this will print the listing number as well and adds the listing to the `List of Listings`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[label={foo},caption={A difficult example in C}, language={C}]{helloworldexample.c}

In \ref{foo} we saw that \dots
\end{document}
```

The `hellowordexample.c` is very short, but sufficient for testing:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
```

[image]